# Can animation parameters only be changed in scripts?

Tags: unity, mecanim

I have a very simple animation parameter in the Animator, a boolean that is "true" when a shooting animation is playing (to stop the game logic from allowing more shooting during a gun recoil animation). I assumed I'd be able to access this in animations, i.e. setting it to true when a shooting animation started, and false when it ended. But I just can't see how to access it in my animations. It's not available under "Add Curve". Am I missing something?

I can do this in other ways, but this just seemed like the cleanest.

[image: Screenshot of animation parameter setup]

Comment: Have you tried creating a state that you transition to every time Shooting is set to true?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, yes, the parameters can only be changed via scripts. To stop the game logic from allowing more shooting, you should NOT be making a parameter here. The Animator doesn't need to know anything about that, it only cares about animation blending and transitions.

Make a private boolean variable in the script that actually triggers the shooting and don't trigger the shooting when (e.g.:) _isShooting is set to true. You can use something like a coroutine to make a set delay.

Animator parameters exist to enable transitions, that's all they do.